# What's the best way to forward traffic on a specific port to another machine?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

The setup I have is this:

`[client01] <-A-> [server01] <-B-> [server02]`

`client01` can access port 9300 on `server01` (connection `A`). `server01` can only access port `9300` on `server02` (connection `B`) **via ssh**. What's the best way to make all traffic on port `9300` to `server01` go to port `9300` on `server02`?

I can successfully do this with an ssh tunnel from `client01` to `server01` to `server02`, but I don't want to have to run ssh on `client01`. When I ssh from `server01` to `server02` forwarding port 9300 (`ssh -g -L9300:localhost:9300 server02` on `server01`), it doesn't work -- am I using the wrong command?

EDIT: added that server02 is only reachable via ssh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this w/ an iptables DNAT rule-- something like:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d x.x.x.x --dport 9300 -j DNAT --to-destination y.y.y.y:9300
```

Substitute in the IP address of server01 for `x.x.x.x` and the address of server02 for `y.y.y.y` and you're set.

This all assumes, of course, that you're running iptables on server01. This also assumes that server02 is using server01 to route traffic back to the Internet. If server02 isn't then this isn't doing to do what you want.

Edit in light of the SSH-only connectivity between the machines:

Your command-line for the SSH port forward looks okay, except that you need a space between the "L" and "9300". You'll also need to be sure that the server01 computer will accept inbound connections on port 9300. Have a look at your iptables INPUT chain in the filter table (`iptables -L INPUT`) to be sure that the traffic will be allowed in.

You'll need to have that tunnel kept up persistently, too.

Comment: Oops, just realized that server02 is only accessible via ssh - I tried creating a tunnel and then setting the `--to-destination` to `127.0.0.1:8080` (the tunnel port), but that didn't work